# Find the indeterminate values of $x_1$ and $y_1$ if $\vec x=(x_1,-2,1,-1)$ and $\vec y=(-2,y_2,-1,-2)$ and $\lVert \vec x\rVert=2\lVert \vec y\lVert$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, vectors, problem-solving

Let $\vec x=(x_1,-2,1,-1)$ and $\vec y=(-2,y_2,-1,-2)$, wich satisfies $\lVert \vec x\rVert=2\lVert \vec y\lVert$. Find the indeterminate values of $x_1$ and $y_1$.

So, assuming $\lVert _\dot{} \lVert =\lVert _\dot{}\lVert_2$, then:

$$\lVert \vec x\rVert:=\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{4} x_i^2\Bigg)^{1/2}=\sqrt {x^2_1+(-2)^2+1+(-1)^2}=\sqrt{x^2_1+6}$$
$$\lVert \vec y\rVert:=\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{4} y_i^2\Bigg)^{1/2}=\sqrt {(-2)^2+y^2_2+(-1)^2+(-2)^2}=\sqrt{y^2_2+9}$$
Then,
$$\sqrt{x^2_1+6}=2\sqrt{y^2_2+9}$$
$$x^2_1+6=4y^2_2+36$$
$$x^2_1=4y^2_2+30$$
$$x_1=\sqrt{4y^2_2+30}$$
Now, can it be said that every $x_1,y_2\in\Bbb R$ satisfies the condition $\lVert \vec x\rVert=2\lVert \vec y\lVert$?
'Cause we can solve for $y_2$ as well:
$$x^2_1=4y^2_1+30$$
$$\implies y_2=\frac{\sqrt{x^2_1-30}}{2}, x^2_1\ge30$$
And it follows that
$$x^2_1\ge30\implies x_1\le -\sqrt{30} \lor x_1\ge \sqrt{30}$$
And so we get: $x_1\in(-\infty,-\sqrt{30}]\cup[\sqrt{30},\infty)$

Now we got the set of solutions: $S=\{(x_1,y_2)|y_2=\frac{\sqrt{x^2_1-30}}{2},x_1\in(-\infty,-\sqrt{30}]\cup[\sqrt{30},\infty)\}$

Is this the proper way to state it?

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It seems fine to me.